# Reading True or False Values in a matrix

Tags: r

I am Completely new to R, and it is being used in my Stats class. We aren't given a book on it either so it is something I am expected to just figure out by looking up.

I am trying to read how many true values are stored in the first column in an 10000 x 2 matrix. for example I run something like:

```
result[,1]=="G" #Here I want to return a number that tells me how many True value there are
```

What command should I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Just sum all the `TRUE` values

`sum(result[,1]=="G")`

this will tell you how many `G`'s there are in the first column of `result`

Comment: This was what I was looking for thank you! Do you have a recommendation for a R Programming book? I'm looking for one with good example to write out as I go.